# Pasar resultado de una función a otra con JS

Tags: javascript

Quiero pasar el resultado de texto a otra función y poderla visualizar en los múltiples archivos html.

```
function publicar(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
    let texto = "";
    let opciones = document.getElementById('opciones').value;
    let encabezado = document.getElementById('encabezado');
    let descripcion = formulario['descripcion'];

    texto = opciones.value +  encabezado.value;
    
    
    document.getElementById('valores').innerHTML=texto; 

    return texto;
        
       
    }
    
    function resultado(){
        mostrar = publicar(texto);
    }
    
    console.log(resultado);
```

Comment: seria bueno que colocara esa imagen en código

Comment: ¿puedes explicarte mejor?  No entiendo lo que pides.  Si quieres que eso funcione en varias páginas pues cargalo en cada una de ellas, ¿no?  Y pon el HTML porque tienes errores seguro al leer las `opciones`

Comment: si pero lo que necesito es que la variable TEXTO la pueda pasar a otra funcion y como seria el tema de cargala? porque como esta dentro de esa funcion no se como puedo ver el valor en otras paginas

Comment: Puedes usar [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para eso, si el usuario no cambia de navegador (pues son variables que se conservan en el navagador). Aparte de eso, cuando haces `texto = opciones.value + encabezado.value` dos cosas a comentarte: 1) opciones ya lo has predefinido con el `value` antes, no hace falta que lo vuelvas a poner. y 2) ¿que es `encabezado`? ¿otro input?  Por eso te pido el HTML

Comment: Amigo ya lo publique

Comment: No pongas imágenes porque no ayudan a que te podamos ayudar mejor, y nos da pereza reescribirlo todo a pelo para hacer nuestras pruebas.

Comment: Ejem, no pongas imágenes **pero pon el html en modo texto** para que podamos ayudarte (perdón si no me di a entender bien)

Comment: No amigo. la verdad soy nuevo y no se como ponerlo modo texto

Comment: Igual que has puesto el otro cacho de código, de la misma forma. Es decir, copias el HTML de tu editor y lo pegas en la pregunta cuando la edites, y luego seleccionas el texto copiado y le das al boton `{}` del editor de este sitio para marcarlo como código.

Comment: Poner modo texto = hacer _copypaste_ de tu código, eso nada más. Para darle el formato de código, agrega triples acentos graves (_backticks_, ```) una línea antes y una después de ese código.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes pasarlo por parametro

```
function publicar(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
    let texto = "";
    let opciones = document.getElementById('opciones').value;
    let encabezado = document.getElementById('encabezado');
    let descripcion = formulario['descripcion'];
    texto = opciones.value +  encabezado.value;
    document.getElementById('valores').innerHTML=texto; 
    return resultado(texto);
}
    
function resultado(texto){
    mostrar = publicar(texto);
}
    
console.log(resultado);
```

Pero esto es poco extraño ya que no veo la necesidad de tener la funcion de `resultado`

```
function publicar(){
    let formulario = document.getElementById('formulario');
    let texto = "";
    let opciones = document.getElementById('opciones').value;
    let encabezado = document.getElementById('encabezado');
    let descripcion = formulario['descripcion'];
    texto = opciones.value +  encabezado.value;
    document.getElementById('valores').innerHTML=texto; 
    return texto;
}
    
console.log(publicar());
```

Espero te haya ayudado, ahora si las funciones estan en archivos separados puedes exportarla y usarla en otro archivo o como decian el el comentario usar el localstorage.

Saludos!